# How do I get write access to EFS from Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-efs

I've created a lambda function.
I created a Elastic File System (EFS) and access points using all the default settings.
I attached the EFS to the lambda function, again just using the defaults.

But! There is no write access to EFS.

What did I miss?

Hope some kind person knows :)

**Notes....**

**Test Node js example:**

```
exports.handler = function(event, ctx, callback) {
    const fs = require("fs");
    fs.mkdir('/mnt/fs/newfolder', { recursive: true }, (err) => {
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            "content-type": "text/html",
            body: (err || "ok").toString()
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, did you ever find an answer? I have been stuck on this for many hours now. Just trying to save an img to EFS from Lambda and have tried all the suggestions. Still getting a Permission Error. Thanks for posting your question!

Comment: @LukeButhman My answer is the 2nd answer. I've since given up on AWS and moved to app engine on google cloud as it's a lot easier.

Answer (score 13):

The aws documentation misses the part about posix user settings, but a blog post explains it.

To add EFS to lambda.

AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess and AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole permissions need to be added to the execution role.

EFS is mounted to lambda at = /mnt/fs EFS Access point path = /mnt/fs

Add a posix user to the acccess point. User 1000, group 1000 & permissions 0777.

As explained in this blog post:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/

Comment: thank you. adding user, group and permission help me a lot

Comment: "Add a posix user to the acccess point. User 1000, group 1000 & permissions 0777" helped to solve my mounting problem.

Answer (score 8):

Your Lambda execution role must have `AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess` attached to it, to write EFS.

> To Add, Go to Lambda > Permission > Execution role and click on the
> role name.

Now, the role will get opened,Click on Add Policy under permissions and add  `AmazonElasticFileSystemClientFullAccess` and `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`

> Also verify if you have properly set root directory path and mount
> point in Lambda & EFS Access point.

If mount point in lambda File System is `/mnt/fs/` then your Root directory path in Access point must be `/fs`

Comment: ok, added that. Still no access though. Does it take a while?

Comment: No its instant. Did cloud-watch logs show any error ?

Comment: Just this: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/mnt/fs/newfolder', I mounted EFS at /mnt/fs.

Comment: Please verify the root directory path and mount point, updated the answer for same.

Comment: Your root directory path must be `/fs` in EFS Access point.

Comment: On the access point it says the "Root directory path" is /.

Comment: It must be `/fs` as your lambda mount point is `/mnt/fs`

Comment: I've changed the "Root directory path" to /fs and /mnt/fs. Both cause Lambda server errors. If I change it back to /  then lambda works again, but back to square one, no file access.

Answer (score 0):

- I had a similar problem and followed all the steps listed here, but nothing resolved it.
- After further exploration, I discovered that when DataSync migrated files from S3 to EFS, it also changed the permissions on the EFS folder.

[image: DataSync changed permission to nfsnobody]

- I was able to resolve this by creating an EC2, mounting EFS, and chown on the directory. I could then save as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem that efs was read-only from lambda. I mapped efs to a ec2 linux instance and found that all files in this efs had "root" ownership. I think this was automatically done when "/" path was created in efs (maybe because I didn't specify USER/GROUP/permissions).

For example when I was logged as ec2-user (default user of the instance) I was able to read efs but not write , obviously because ec2-user isn't root. The permissions for the folders were
drwxr-xr-x, which means only root was able to write and nobody else. Two different fixes both worked well:
(a) sudo chmod -R 777 efs
(b) sudo chown -R efs
But 'b' is better as it changes ownershipt to ec2-user which also allows me to work with efs files from ec2 instance without 'sudo'
Hope it helps!!